# The Lorentz group is only equal to $O(1,3)$ if $c=1$?

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, group-theory

Consider the matrix
$$\eta_c=\left[
 \begin{array}{c|c}
  -c^2 &  0 \\
\hline
  0  & I 
 \end{array}
 \right]$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix in $\mathbb R^{3\times 3}$. If $c\neq 1$ and $A\in\mathbb R^{4\times 4}$, then $\eta_1=A^t\eta_1 A$ ("$A$ is an element of $O(1,3)$") and $\eta_c=A^t\eta_c A$ ("$A$ is a Lorentz transformation") are not equivalent, are they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Sylvester's law of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia) states that for any quadratic form $\eta'$ with the same signature as $\eta_1$ there exists some $A$ such that $\eta' = A^t\eta_1 A$. It is not hard to show that $\Lambda\mapsto A^{-1}\Lambda A $ is an isomorphism between the isometry group of $\eta_1$ and $\eta'$, see also [this math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1884426/143136).

Hence all quadratic forms with signature -1,1,1,1 have a group isomorphic to $\mathrm{O}(1,3)$ as their isometry group, in particular all your $\eta_c$.